# Return value from JSON, not the children count

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Instead of printing the number of children a specific node in flare.json has, I want to print the real value of the child node from flare.json. When hovering over a parent node (a node with children), I want the sum of all children (and sub-children, ...) values printed.

There are similar questions (not specific d3) suggesting a recursive function. But all the code snippets did not help me so far. Does d3 ship with some function to achieve this behavior?

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .50 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });


d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/master/test/data/flare.json", function(error, root) {

  if (error) throw error;

  var data = root;
  
  var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
    .data(partition.nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; }) // hide inner ring
   .attr("d", arc)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
   .style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
    .style("fill", howToFill)
   .each(stash)
   .on("mouseover", onMouseOver)
   .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);


   var value = function(d) { return d.value; };
});

function stash(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
  return function(t) {
    var b = i(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  };
}

function howToFill(d) {
  if ( d.name == "-" ) {
    return "#fff";
  } else {
    return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
  }
}

// Mouseover

function onMouseOver(d) {
 d3.select(this)
 svg.append("text")
 .style("text-anchor", "middle")
 .text(function() { return d.name + " - " + d.value; });
}

function onMouseOut(d) {
 d3.select(this)
 svg
  .select("text")
 .remove();
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What should layout, vis, operator, ... become?

Comment: The values or sums of the values respectively stored in the json (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/master/test/data/flare.json) for each node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version of your code which displays the actual counts:

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .50 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/master/test/data/flare.json", function(error, root) {

  if (error) throw error;

  // Deep copy of the root object (for use by the mouseover function)
  // since the d3 partitioning will modify root and only keep
  // partitioning details:
  var initialData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(root));
  
  var data = root;
  
  var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
    .data(partition.nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; }) // hide inner ring
   .attr("d", arc)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
   .style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
    .style("fill", howToFill)
   .each(stash)
   .on("mouseover", onMouseOver)
   .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);


  var value = function(d) { return d.value; };
  
  // Let's move the onMouseOver function inside the json extractor in order
  // to easily work with "initialData":
  function onMouseOver(d) {
   d3.select(this)
   svg.append("text")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   //.text(function() { return d.name + " - " + d.value; });
    .text(function() {
      return d.name + " - " + sumValue(findElem(initialData, d.name, d.depth, 0));
    });
  }
});

function stash(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
  return function(t) {
    var b = i(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  };
}

function howToFill(d) {
  if ( d.name == "-" ) {
    return "#fff";
  } else {
    return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
  }
}

function onMouseOut(d) {
 d3.select(this)
 svg
  .select("text")
 .remove();
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

function findElem(elmt, name, searchedDepth, currDepth) {
  if (currDepth > searchedDepth)
    return undefined
  else if (elmt.name == name && searchedDepth == currDepth) {
    return elmt;
  }
  else if (elmt.children) {
    var result = elmt.children.map(c => findElem(c, name, searchedDepth, currDepth + 1)).filter(x => x);
    return result.length == 1 ? result[0] : undefined;
  }
  else
    return undefined;
}

function sumValue(elmt) {
  try {
    if (elmt.children)
      return elmt.children.map(c => sumValue(c)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    else
      return elmt.value;
  } catch(err) {
    // The try catch is there to hide the exception due to the "data"
    // value which is not supported. Not sure how to cleanly fix this
    // corner case:
    return "error";
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

During the mouseover, let's first find back the actual `data element` which is hovered. The thing is, the d3 layout partitioning removes data information from the model... So that's why we need to get back to the original data to find back the node in question:

```
function findElem(elmt, name, searchedDepth, currDepth) {
  if (currDepth > searchedDepth)
    return undefined
  else if (elmt.name == name && searchedDepth == currDepth) {
    return elmt;
  }
  else if (elmt.children) {
    var result = elmt.children.map(c => findElem(c, name, searchedDepth, currDepth + 1)).filter(x => x);
    return result.length == 1 ? result[0] : undefined;
  }
  else
    return undefined;
}
```

Which is called from the mouseover function this way:

```
.text( function() {
  return d.name + " - " + sumValue(findElem(initialData, d.name, d.depth, 0));
});
```

where `initialData` is a deep copy of the `json` (otherwise, since the extracted json `root` is modified by the partitioning, we would loose original data information).

Notice the usage of the `depth` in order to handle the fact that different nodes can have the same label (for instance there are several nodes at different depths named "data").

---

Once we have the node in question, we can recursively sum all children values this way:

```
function sumValue(elmt) {
  if (elmt.children)
    return elmt.children.map(c => sumValue(c)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  else
    return elmt.value;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but you may want to tell OP that the deep cloning won't work for some values, like date objects for instance.

Comment: Nice catch! I think you meant the `data` element. Not sure if there's a clean way to fix it.

Comment: No, there is no issue neither with the data nor with your answer! I'm just warning you that deep cloning with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))` won't work with certain values, like dates (`16-Mar-2018`), for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet and the explanation of the findElem() and sumValue() functions. Can you specify the misbehavior of the `data` node?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Possibly related to data being a reserved property of javascript objects? Might need the help of javascript experts on this one.

Comment: This is not the case. When using the same code with different data (same structure, but different names and values), the same problem appears with other nodes, too.

Comment: Using your code and logging the error to console gives: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
    at sumValue ((index):154)
    at SVGTextElement.<anonymous> ((index):105)
    at SVGTextElement.<anonymous> (d3.min.js:3)
    at d3.min.js:3
    at Y (d3.min.js:1)
    at Array.Co.each (d3.min.js:3)
    at Array.Co.text (d3.min.js:3)
    at SVGPathElement.onMouseOver ((index):105)
    at SVGPathElement.__onmouseover (d3.min.js:1)```

Comment: I guess I have found the error: Two nodes have the name `data` - there seems to be a problem with nodes which have identical names. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/t9op59kt/3/ I changed the name of the `data` nodes to `data1` and `data2` and it works without further changes in the code...

Comment: Indeed, this probably is the issue. We can try to include some logic to handle this.

Comment: @ottlngr I have updated the demo with a version which handles different nodes having the same lable. This makes use of the depth of a node.